# One way ticket for Australia

Tags: visas, tickets, australia

My mom is visiting me, with a European passport and three months visa. Does she need to buy a one way ticket or a two way ticket? The travel agency told her she needs to buy a 2 way ticket.

Comment: What is "European passport"? UK, Greece, Albania and Ukraine all are European but (at least two of them) have different conditions for visiting Australia.

Comment: Why buy a one way ticket? If she's visiting, she'll want to come back, won't she?

Answer (score 4):

According to http://uk.embassy.gov.au/lhlh/immi_travel.html

> There is no requirement to have a return ticket when you arrive in Australia. However officers at the border need to be satisfied that visitors, working holiday maker and temporary residents are intending to and have the means to depart Australia before their visa expires. While not a mandatory requirement, you may wish to carry a copy of your bank statement to demonstrate you have sufficient funds to purchase an airline ticket to depart Australia.

So it doesn't appear to be mandatory.

However it is likely a good idea. Both because it may make it easier to convince the border guard you are a legitimate visitor and because on long haul journeys returns are usually significantly cheaper than two singles. Even if you end up paying a change fee the return may still come out ahead.

Comment: Hi there,no my mom she is not return to Greece,cause she's australian.But was in the country for 15 years,and then,she went back in Greece,and have invalid money payment,so after when she lost her husbant,she decide to come back in Australia,for ever,her australian passport had expire,and she lost her citizenship yellow paper,that way she make Greek passport and tourist visa holder,when come Australia she will not return and she planning to find her citiznship paper in Australia,and then reaply her australian passport.

Answer (score 1):

If she is visiting, she's planning to get back, no ?  So she eventually need a ticket back.

It might be cheaper to buy the 2 tickets at once.

If she does not have a set return date (within the visa date restrictions), she could get an open return ticket (which is not cheaper AFAIK ?)

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: a bad one, maybe ? :-)